# Дописать функцию на Java-Script

Tags: javascript

Есть объект heights с десяткой самых высоких зданий мира. Ключи этого объекта — названия зданий, а значения — высоты в метрах. Выясните, достигнет ли суммарная высота этих построек стратосферы.Стратосфера располагается на высоте от 11 до 50 километров. Мы сохранили высоту её нижней границы в переменной stratoHeight.
Постарайтесь сделать решение как можно более коротким (не более 3 строчек кода) и изящным.

```
const heights = {
  burjKhalifa: 828,
  tokyoSkyTree: 634,
  shanghaiTower: 632,
  abrajAlBait: 601,
  cantonTower: 600,
  pingAnFinanceCentre: 600,
  lotteWorldTower: 555,
  cnTower: 553,
  oneWorldTradeCenter: 541,
  ostankinoTower: 540
};

const stratoHeight = 11000;

const sumHeights = Object.values(heights).reduce(function (result, current) {
 //тут допишите ваше решение
}, 0);

console.log(sumHeights >= stratoHeight);
```

Comment: Вам нужно прочитать документацию по методу reduce и написать одну строчку. Вперёд!

Answer (score 1):

Вот весь ответ! Спасибо Alexey Ten!

```
return result + current
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
const heights = {
  burjKhalifa: 828,
  tokyoSkyTree: 634,
  shanghaiTower: 632,
  abrajAlBait: 601,
  cantonTower: 600,
  pingAnFinanceCentre: 600,
  lotteWorldTower: 555,
  cnTower: 553,
  oneWorldTradeCenter: 541,
  ostankinoTower: 540
};

const stratoHeight = 11000;

const sumHeights = Object.values(heights).reduce(function (result, current) {
 return current+result;
}, 0);

console.log(sumHeights >= stratoHeight);
```

Comment: Спасибо Петров Макарий!